# Vue.js without Gulp, Grunt, Bower, Browserify, Webpack, Yeoman, NPM, CLI?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, vue.js

I have a .Net Project, that will require a lot of dom manipulation, and I wanted to get involved with Vue.js as it seems the lightest weight. I was wondering if anyone had any insight into getting Vue.js to work within Visual Studio?

I have attempted the `tooling route with Gulp, Bower, Browserify etc` and decided against it after several days of trying to get Vue.js to work with all the tools, within visual studio.

Is there a way to just include Vue.js via a script link?
What would I miss out on? Can I still build components and do the the html mark up with `v-bind` etc?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started

Comment: @Quentin Thank you, I have read the guide. This guide was one of the reasons that I chose to go with Vue. However my question is more related to what will be lost with just a script link. As far as I can tell, just the "require" and "export" type of functionality is lost.

Comment: Yes, you can't `require` stuff in the browser. Luckily most frameworks are (or offer a) monolithic version that you can simply include as a `<script>` tag and get on with your life. If you don't shy away from manual dependency management, or don't have that many dependencies in the first place, don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Languages like .NET and Java have tons of built in libraries that offer a lot of functionality built in.  JS by comparison has very little.  That is why JS has "lost their mind" with dependencies, everything is built in.  Think of it this way: Every system import you do is equivalent to one JS dependency, with possibly many others.  It might be worth decoupling your front-end from your back-end, and then not having to worry about dependency hell in one monolithic project.

Comment: @christopherclark you lose the ability to write [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and get the extra overhead of having the templates compile at runtime.

Comment: @christopher - That being said, this is a highly subjective question that is not a good fit for Stack Overflow's strictly technical Q&A format. Prepare for getting this question closed.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not sure it's really subjective, the question is clearly "what do you miss out on by including Vue via a script tag?"

Comment: @craig_h Hm... I perceive it as a "rant+what do you guys recommend I should do" type of question, which would be OT. It's somewhat in a gray area, I have not voted to close it myself, but I think it could use "less opinion/more beef".

Comment: @Tomalak I have removed the background information that has lead to my frustration

Comment: Well the answer to both of your question is "Yes", as detailed in the links that have been posted. (I'm doing a small personal project right now using this approach as well, including Vue.js via the `<script>` tag and it works well enough for my purposes. The biggest "issue" for me is that I have to define templates as strings, loosing out on syntax highlighting and autocompletion in Visual Studio Code)

Comment: I've worked with manual dependency management and knockout.js, which is similar to vue, on medium-sized projects. It's can get a bit tedious, but getting all those helper tools to work properly is at least as tedious, and it adds another layer of abstraction and obfuscation, plus a hefty learning curve. Pick your poison. At the very least you must have done it manually once to be able to appreciate or gauge the things these tools do.

Comment: @UnholySheep You can also define templates in html with custom markups and editors will recognize them.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 please clarify: Are you referring to Single-File Components (which don't work if you include vue.js via the `<script>` tag)? Or do you know a way to make editors recognize HTML embedded in strings in JavaScript?

Comment: @UnholySheep You can write `<my-temp></my-temp>` in html and `template: '#my-temp'` in options in `new Vue()`, I've seen it in others' jsfiddles. [doc link](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#template) Not familiar with `Vue.component()` but I guess this option also work there.

Comment: @UnholySheep Just found a similar (and even more simple) solution called [inline-template](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates) which roughly goes `<my-component inline-template></my-component>`